# System running out of memory when Python multiprocessing Pool is used?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize my code to find the similarity matrix using  multiprocessing module in Python. It works fine when I use the small np.ndarray with 10 X 15 elements. But, when I scale my np.ndarray to 3613 X 7040 elements, system runs out of memory.

Below, is my code.

```
import multiprocessing 
from multiprocessing import Pool
## Importing Jacard_similarity_score
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score

# Function for finding the similarities between two np arrays
def similarityMetric(a,b):
    return (jaccard_similarity_score(a,b))

## Below functions are used for Parallelizing the scripts
 # auxiliary funciton to make it work
def product_helper1(args):
    return (similarityMetric(*args))

def parallel_product1(list_a, list_b):
    # spark given number of processes
    p = Pool(8) 
    # set each matching item into a tuple
    job_args = getArguments(list_a,list_b)    
    # map to pool
    results = p.map(product_helper1, job_args)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    return (results)

## getArguments function is used to get the combined list 
def getArguments(list_a,list_b):
    arguments = []
    for i in list_a:
        for j in list_b:
            item = (i,j)
            arguments.append(item)
    return (arguments)
```

Now when I run the below code, system runs out of memory and gets hanged. I am passing two numpy.ndarrays testMatrix1 and testMatrix2 which are of size (3613, 7040)

```
resultantMatrix = parallel_product1(testMatrix1,testMatrix2)
```

I am new to using this module in Python and trying to understand where I am going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `getArguments` makes a list of every possible pair of rows from the two matrices, so `3613*3613` items. On my machine, that's takes a couple of GB of RAM. Try using `itertools.product(list_a, list_b)` instead - this should generate the pairs as they're needed, without storing them all in memory at once.

Answer (score 2):

Odds are, the problem is just combinatoric explosion. You're trying to realize all the pairs in the main process up front, rather than generating them live, so you're storing a huge amount of memory. Assuming the `ndarray`s contain `double` values, which become Python `float`, then the memory usage of the `list` returned by `getArguments` is roughly the cost of a `tuple` and two `float`s per pair, or about:

```
3613 * 7040 * (sys.getsizeof((0., 0.)) + sys.getsizeof(0.) * 2)
```

On my 64 bit Linux system, that means ~2.65 GB of RAM on Py3, or ~2.85 GB on Py2, before the workers even do anything.

If you can process the data in a streaming fashion using a generator, so arguments are produced lazily and discarded when no longer needed, you could probably reduce memory usage dramatically:

```
import itertools

def parallel_product1(list_a, list_b):
    # spark given number of processes
    p = Pool(8) 
    # set each matching item into a tuple
    # Returns a generator that lazily produces the tuples
    job_args = itertools.product(list_a,list_b)    
    # map to pool
    results = p.map(product_helper1, job_args)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    return (results)
```

This still requires all the results to fit in memory; if `product_helper` returns `float`s, then the expected memory usage for the `result` `list` on a 64 bit machine would still be around 0.75 GB or so, which is pretty large; if you can process the results in a streaming fashion, iterating the results of `p.imap` or even better, `p.imap_unordered` (the latter returns results as computed, not in the order the generator produced the arguments) and writing them to disk or otherwise ensuring they're released in memory quickly would save a lot of memory; the following just prints them out, but writing them to a file in some reingestable format would also be reasonable.

```
def parallel_product1(list_a, list_b):
    # spark given number of processes
    p = Pool(8) 
    # set each matching item into a tuple
    # Returns a generator that lazily produces the tuples
    job_args = itertools.product(list_a,list_b)    
    # map to pool
    for result in p.imap_unordered(product_helper1, job_args):
        print(result)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried using itertools as you suggested and at least system isn't running out of memory now. Can you tell me how long it took for the program to complete? It takes me 55 minutes for generating the resultantMatrix (output) without using multiprocessing module. It has been like more than an hour now and still is running on a 64 bit 8 core machine when I try to parallelize. Could you please let me know if I am missing any important prerequisite for using this module.

Comment: I encountered similar problem in  'R' and I got the execution time of my program from couple of hours to  '5 minutes' by using doPar and foreach packages. I went through few blogs on Google and I got to know multiprocessing module in Python is similar to foreach in R. So, I am wondering if I am missing any important information while using the same in Python?

Answer (score 0):

The `map` method sends all data to the workers via inter-process communication. As currently done, this consumes a huge amount of resources, because you're sending

What I would suggest it to modify `getArguments` to make a list of tuple of *indices* in the matrix that need to be combined. That's only two numbers that have to be sent to the worker process, instead of two rows of a matrix! Each worker then knows which rows in the matrix to use.

Load the two matrices and store them in global variables *before* calling `map`. This way *every* worker has access to them. And as long as they're not modified in the workers, the OS's virtual memory manager will not copy identical memory pages, keeping memory usage down.